# I'm really confused with .htaccess config

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.php /article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /404
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

The above code **removed the .php extension and semantic URL**.

But my real trouble is **enabling trailing slashes and redirect if .php is encountered**

- If the URL is **http://example.org/login/** it's giving me a 404 instead i want it to redirect back to **http://example.org/login**
- If the URL is **http://example.org/login.php** it should redirect to **http://example.org/login**

Comment: A http status 500 does not really tell what the issue is, since that only is the information the http server hands out to untrusted clients. Instead you need to look into your http server's error log file to read what the _actual_ issue is.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of work, a online htaccess tester is a must, and will show you that you have errors in your htaccess. I always use [this one](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). I've tried a few things, and hope the following will work as you described:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Strip a dot and 2-4 chars of the end, and add a slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ $1/ [NC]

# If there is one query string (you can change [a-z] to 
# a specific query), extract the value and append between
# two slashes, discard the original query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-z]+\=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/%1/ [NC,QSD]
```